# jquery autocomplete is rendering unfiltered data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery auto complete for auto suggestion. The suggestion drop down is showing entire list instead of filtered list.

**fiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/joshi101/zn609sdj/7/

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' />
```

**jquery**

```
    var json = [{"full_name": "joye dave", "username": "jd"}, {"full_name": "rob", "username": "r"}, {"full_name": "jhon key", "username": "jk"}, {"full_name": "alpacino", "username": "ap"}, {"full_name": "Julia", "username": "Julia"}];
$('input').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
     response( $.map( json , function(i){
            return{
              id: i.username,
              value: i.full_name
            }
          }))
        },
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "input" ).val( ui.item.id );
    return false;
  },

});
```

I have seen similar code working during my search but not getting any clue why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the results to be alphabetically sorted, then need to sort your object. Autocomplete doesn't do that for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/9zw3fu7t/

E.g.

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.full_name.toLowerCase() < b.full_name.toLowerCase())
    return -1;
  if (a.full_name.toLowerCase() > b.full_name.toLowerCase())
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

json.sort(compare);
```

I got the sort function here: [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

To get your example to work though, there are a few gotchas.

Firstly your example isn't actually doing autocomplete – when you type in 'j' for example, it's returning everything containing a 'j' anywhere in the word. I don't think that's what you want. So you need to use regex matching to test against the start of the word.

Secondly, once you do that, your `$.map` function needs to be moved: https://jsfiddle.net/7ky8whx2/

Here's the full code:

```
var json = [{"full_name": "joye dave", "username": "jd"}, {"full_name": "rob", "username": "r"}, {"full_name": "jhon key", "username": "jk"}, {"full_name": "alpacino", "username": "ap"}, {"full_name": "Julia", "username": "Julia"}];

var transformJson = function(json) {
  return $.map(json, function(i) {
    return {
      value: i.full_name,
      id: i.username,
    }
  });
}

function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.full_name.toLowerCase() < b.full_name.toLowerCase())
    return -1;
  if (a.full_name.toLowerCase() > b.full_name.toLowerCase())
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

json.sort(compare);

$( "input" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
    response( 
      $.grep( 
        transformJson(json), 
        function( item ){
          found = matcher.test( item.value );
          return found;
        }
      ) 
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sorting, it is working now. But why autocomplete is not filtering it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

> *The suggestion drop down is showing entire list instead of sorted list.*

What you want here is not *sorting*, it is *filtering*.

In your `source` function, you need to filter which values to use from `json`. You can *also* sort, map, etc. here. Something like

```
response(
  json.filter(
    function (jsonItem) {
      let sanitizedInput = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
      return jsonItem.full_name.match(sanitizedInput);
    }
  )
  .map(/* transform to {id, value} or else in here if need be */)
  .sort(/* sort data in here if need be */)
)
```

This uses [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). If you want *sorting* also, check the hint given by [geoidesic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52905651/1269732)'s answer. Check [the behavior of `source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) when passing a function to it for full information.